# empty value after mysql update php

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update, is-empty

i made a lot of research around here and Google but i cannot find an answer to this problem.

I update a field in a MySQL database with following code:

```
public function registerPubKey() {
    
    $stmt = $this->cn->prepare('UPDATE sb_user SET pubkey= ? WHERE email= ?');
    $exres = $stmt->execute(array($this->info["pubkey"], $this->info["email"]));

    if ($exres == false) {
        $resultArray["result"] = "Error registering public key";
        echo json_encode($resultArray);
        exit;
    }
    
    $resultArray["result"] = "success";
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
```

I'm sure that all works except that the field in the database is empty. I dumped the private variable $info and it contains the pubkey (pubkey is a base64 string).

I noticed that if I change the update query with an INSERT, the value is inserted correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely because you're trying to `UPDATE` non existent rows. Try adding a `ON DUPLICATE KEY` before. See [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). `UPDATE` returns nothing if the row does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer. I will check and let you know

Comment: Oh my god...i am a little retarded xD I was passing the wrong value in the WHERE condition.

`It's likely because you're trying to UPDATE non existent rows.`

in Parker answer was the solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and validated that:

- the row existed, and
- the `execute` parameters were valid and correct

The `PDO::errorInfo()` function can provide insight into what's actually happening to cause the update to fail:

```
if (! $stmt->execute($params) ) {
    $resultArray["result"] = print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true);
}
```

In my case, I got the message `The user specified as a definer ('user'@'172.20.%.%') does not exist`. Since this was a database snapshot restored to a different subnet, the error message makes sense and the user in-fact did not exist.